# trigger function when mobx observable is changed

Tags: reactjs, observable, mobx

I currently trying to create a function which should be triggered in my react component when my observable in my store is changed (i'm using mobx).

this is my store =>

```
class myStore{
@observable myVariable
}
```

this is my react component =>

```
@observer
export default class MyComponent etends React.component {

    render(){
    //rendering stuff here
    }

    someFunctionTriggeredByObservableChanged(){   // maybe a intercept or observe from mobx ?
    }

}
```

I was wondering if i could use maybe intercept or observe from mobx directly in my react component ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `reaction`

```
@inject('store')
@observer
export default class MyComponent etends React.component {

  componentDidMount() {
    reaction(
      () => this.props.store.myVariable,
      () => {
        console.log('reaction');
        // do your stuff
      }
    )
  }

  ...
}
```

[MobX Reaction Doc](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/reaction.html)